# Flink1.10 why does DDL not support create view and create function?

Tags: apache-flink, ddl, create-view, create-function

Flink1.10 why does DDL not support create view and create function ?

Answer (score 0):

I see [`create function`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/create.html#create-function) in the DDL documentation. But `create view` is only supported by the SQL Client in Flink 1.10, and not DDL (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sqlClient.html#sql-views). However, it has been added for Flink 1.11 -- see https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/11727 and [FLIP-71](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-71%3A+E2E+View+support+in+FLINK+SQL).